# Designer can't load reference 'Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms'

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, reference, designer

I have 2 forms : B inherits of A.

If I add an InputPanel control on B, i have no problem.
If I add an InputPanel control on A and B, i have no problem.
But if I add an InputPanel control only on A, I'm unable to open the designer for form B.

The erros is :

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=969db8053d3322ac' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I read many things about that, and found nothing to solve this. It seems that the designer is unable to load the dll `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.dll` only when the input panel is in base form.

I tried :

- Add the dll in GAC.
- Create a new form (ex: C inherits A)
- Create an empty project

I don't have any problem to compile my project.

Thanks for your time

EDIT : A reboot fix it. I don't know if it's something i did and the reboot.. or only the reboot. Now i can open any form in designer.

Comment: Review the References and verify that all projects target CF version 3.5.  Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms is an assembly in CF 2.0

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution for that issue.

1. Check in your GAC if Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms v2.0 is already loaded.
2. Uninstall it `gagutil.exe /u Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms`
3. Install the new version of the assembly (which is required by the designer) `gacutil.exe /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Microsoft.Windowsce.Forms.dll"`
4. Reboot your computer.

Theses steps should fix the problem.

Comment: Great answer, this solved my problem. Thank you.
Can you please correct "gagutil" to "gacutil" in step 2 description?